# JavaScript for the appearance of new content on clock and hiding main content in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JS isnt my forte, but I need to create functional like [here](https://elizion.org/#home) (left fixed menu).

In brief we have main content and menu with links. Click on one of them - we got all new content (old fade anywhere) and button to return it. Like in example above.

Maybe there is some plugin/library for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There several plugins that allow to do such type of animations, I would recommend you to use https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js as it works good, easy to use (all that you need to do is to create necessary html of you page and init plugin, `$('#yourwrapper').smoothState();` after that all links on your page will be handled via AJAX and replace the content) and well supported, so in case of any issues in implementing you will easily find answers.

Here is demo example with sidebar fade animations: https://rawgit.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/master/demos/sidebar/page-four.html

Answer (score 2):

Fading out some content and fading in some other content is really easy with jQuery. Just wrap your initial content and secondary in wrappers, position and needed and set `display:none` for the new content/menus. Then something as simple as this would work, no libraries required:

```
$('.eventHandler').on('click', function(){
  $('.initialContent').fadeOut();
  $('.newContent').fadeIn();
})
```

As for cool libraries, I like [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/), and [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) is nice for simple animations (like those hopping circles while your reference page loads).

Hope this helps!